# Is this sequential function chart correct?

Tags: control, robotics

I have to draw the sequential function chart of a robotic arm  which in the beginning of a process is in the position A. If it gets an impulse from the sensor S1 it moves to the left and for  5 seconds reaches the B position,stays for 5 seconds in this position and then gets back to the initial position. If it gets an impulse from the sensor S2, it  moves to the right and for five seconds reaches the position C. It stays for five seconds in this position and then moves back to the initial position.

[image]

Is my SFC correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe so, except that the initialisation or start position is supposed to be represented by a double-lined square.

Generally reaching a certain position, here B or C is monitored by a sensor and not a timer. This is to be certain that the arm is actually in that position. This is however a design matter and has nothing to do with the correctness of the SFC itself.